# Change WebService endpoint address at run time

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I used Netbeans to generate Web Sevice client code from WSDL url.
But I can't change endpoint address at run time using code.

Please help me to solve that problem!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

1) Cast `port` to `BindingProvider` and specify `BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY` property

```
MyService service = new MyService();
MyPort port = service....
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://New.Endpoint/service");
```

2) You can call the generated service constructor which takes WSDL URL as parameter.

```
QName qname = new QName("http://serviceuri/", "service");
String wsdl = "http://New.Endpoint/service?wsdl";
MyServiec service = new MyServiec(new URL(wsdl), qname);
MyPort port = check...;
```

Comment: In my case use option onre and two and keep localhost... then fail...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all from you service's constructor. JAX-WS will have generated various forms of the constructor for you. This is basically same as what is mentioned as solution #2 in Chandra's answer above.

**However I do not think you want code the namespace and the service name once again as is done in that answer**. Simply do:

```java
URL wsdl = new URL("http://New.Endpoint/service?wsdl");
MyService wsService = new MyService(wsdlURL);
```